# Vue: Data is not changing with Vuex getter?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a modal component that I was triggered when different components mutate the `triggerModalState` field.  I have a getter in my Vuex store called `getFulfillmentModalState`.  The modal is driven off of the local data field called `dialog`, which I have set to be the value of the getter `this.$store.getters.getFulfillmentModalState`.  I am checking the value of `this.$store.getters.getFulfillmentModalState`, and it is `true` after I trigger the modal, but the `dialog` data is still false.  What am I doing wrong here?

```html
<template>
    <div class="fulfillment-modal-component">
        <v-row justify="center">
            <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="290">
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-btn color="rgba(53, 87, 151, 0.85)" text @click="changeModalState(true)">Cancel</v-btn>
                        <v-btn color="rgba(53, 87, 151, 0.85)" text @click="changeModalState(false)">Continue</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
        </v-row>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapState} from 'vuex';
    import store from './../../store/store';

    export default {
        name: 'fulfillment-modal',

        mounted() {

        },

        data() {
            return {
                dialog: this.$store.getters.getFulfillmentModalState
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dialog` isn't reactive in this case because it's declared in `data()`. Move `dialog` to [`computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to make it reactive:

```js
//...
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //dialog: /*..*/   // move to computed
    }
  },
  computed: {
    dialog() {
      return this.$store.getters.getFulfillmentModalState
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/loving-cache-ncs6h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)